# regex "something or nothing" match

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I'm trying to build a regex that will capture the `TEXT*` from both files below

```
/A/B/C/D/TEXT1/TEXT2.TEXT3.log
/A/B/C/D/TEXT1/TEXT2.trc
```

I came out with

```
/A/B/C/D/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)?(?:\.)?([^\/]+)\.(log|trc)
```

It doesn't work as I expect.

Basically, I need to capture all `TEXT1`, `TEXT2`, and `TEXT3` fields (if they exist) from both examples for further use; if not, as is the case with the second line, only `TEXT1` and `TEXT2`.

Comment: What about `\/A\/B\/C\/D\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)?(?:\.)?([^\/]+)\.(log|trc)`?

Comment: please be more specific in what exactly you are trying to look for and what was your result?

Comment: You need to be more specific; don't just say what will match, but also what won't (and describe in words or examples what captures you want, which you did do). Here's another pattern that will match both of your examples: `.*` Also, the title is absolutely uninformative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\/A\/B\/C\/D\/([^\/]+)\/(\w+)?(?:\.(\w+))?\.(?:log|trc)
```

In case you have other characters than just letters, numbers or underscore (captured by `\w`), you can limit to `[^.]+`:

```
\/A\/B\/C\/D\/([^\/]+)\/([^.]+)?(?:\.([^.]+))?\.(?:log|trc)
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/lN5jQ3/1)  and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lN5jQ3/2)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the end of line anchor?

```
/\/([^\/]\/[^\/]?)\.(log|trc)$/
```